# Reduce LLC profits by putting towards spouse's IRA?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, ira, limited-liability-company

I have a full time job. I also own a LLC (sole proprietor). I have some profits from my LLC this year. My spouse and I file jointly. My spouse is not currently employed.

Can I move the profits from the LLC to my spouse's IRA to deduct it from our federal income tax burden?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the US, you can set up a spousal IRA and deduct it from your taxable income you qualify.
https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits
It won't come directly out of the business, but it is an above the line deduction that reduces AGI.

Comment: This is true even if he didn't have an LLC and was an employee.  The LLC doesn't give any benefits in this case.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill Right the only way Richard could defer more taxation specifically from having the LLC would be setting up a qualified plan, but that would have to have been set up earlier.